# Detecting JavaScript errors in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome does not appear to give any indication that a page has JavaScript errors, unless you open up the JavaScript Console to check.

Is there any way to have an indication that there were errors, and then automatically open the JavaScript Console? Can the JavaScript console be opened from JavaScript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Chrome does not have a native ability to alert you to Javascript errors.  However, this Chrome extension will show an alert icon in the address bar when a Javascript error occurs:

https://github.com/barbushin/javascript-errors-notifier

The extension can be installed here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd

Comment: @Evgenii Extension does not show ads. It's 100% open source https://github.com/barbushin/javascript-errors-notifier and published version is same as on GitHub, so you can check it by yourself.

Comment: Notice: It doesn't work if you use webpack dev-server.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot open the console directly from your JavaScript code. And as far as I know, only Opera has the option to display the console automatically, right after any error occurs.

Comment: IE will display the console after errors.  I forget offhand where the magical radio button is though.

Answer (score -4):

No. Even calling `console.log` will not display the console.

Comment: calling console.log() can dump things in console. It will not make the console show up, so you need to open it yourself, by pressing F12 and then click console tab.