# Chrome: how can I notice a Javascript error right way with opening "Inspect Element" pane?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use Chrome and Firefox to develop a website.

I like Firefox's Firebug, which allows me to see if a Javascript error exists right way without opening Firebug window. However, for unknown reason, my app runs slow inside Firefox on my laptop.

The app runs very fast within Chrome. I want to always use Chrome. However, to see if there is a Javascript bug, I have to open  the "Inspect Element" pane and go to the Console tab, which is really inconvenient. Is there any way in Chrome that allows me to see Javascript bug right way? Plugin or not?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What about pressing F12 - less work than your approach. (Though it's not exactly what you want)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting JavaScript errors in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595240/detecting-javascript-errors-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaScript Errors Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd?hl=en) might be what you want.

*Note:* As several have pointed out, this extension actually collects usage statistics from your browser.

@santon suggests using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/fhbooopdkjpkogooopbmabepipljagfn) version of the plugin, which apparently doesn't do that. Though there are only 3 reviews and no comments, it might be worth trying it out.

Comment: NB: The fine print on that extension notes that it pulls in a script that will "collect the usage statistics from your browser". Ick. :/

Comment: The whole note: We are always trying to find a way to continuously improve JavaScript Errors Notifier, thus we've chosen Fairshare and Intenta as our trusted partner, which will collect the usage statistics from your browser. It's anonymous and will not include any of your privacy data. We concern about your data security as you always do. Please learn more about Fairshare privacy policy at https://fairsharelabs.com/analytics. Anyway, there is also alternative extension version, that does not collect any statistics: https://goo.gl/IRbqnY

Answer (score 1):

It isn't on the console tab by default? My Developer Tools instance seems to automatically start on the console tab if there are errors, but I have my instance set to start popped out of the main Chrome window. With the Developer Tools window docked to the bottom or side of the main Chrome window it starts on the Elements tab.

It's faster to access the dev tools and console if you use keyboard shortcuts as well. Press Shift + Ctrl + I to open Developer Tools, and then if the console isn't immediately visible, hit Escape. Escape toggles the console on the Elements tab. If your Developer Tools starts on different tab than Console or Elements then I don't know what to say.

Comment: Ahhh, you can use F12 instead of Shift+Ctrl+I to open the dev tools too, thanks for pointing that out Pushkin. So really the fastest way would be F12 or F12 <wait> Esc.